# How to update and add attributes in a XML file by using python pandas data frame

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree, xml.etree

I am new to the XML, Is there any efficient way to match text using pandas data frame and update XML file ?

This is a small part of my large XML file which still follows the appropriate format.

**XML file** (input.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
   <design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">
      <sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
         <feature number="48">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz" />
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
        </mwan>
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
            <xyz abc="trt" id="abc" />
            <per fre="acc" value="abc" />
            <per fre="xyz" value="abc" />
            <per fre="yy" value="abc" />
         </mwan>
      </sec>
      #file continue....
   </design>
</brand>
```

**Data frame** (to use as input):

```
                name       Volum_5mb      Volum_40mb     Volum_70mb
1     M_20_K40745170         89.00           44.00         77.00
2     M_20_K40745171         77.00           65.00         94.00
```

I would like to match elements from `name` column and if match then use rest of column to make new attribute as below. For example, if elements (`M_20_K40745170`) from `df['name']` is present/matched then update the corresponding node with following lines respectively in the output file.

```
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="44.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="77.00"/>
```

and so on.

I want the output file to looks like

**Desired XML** (output.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
   <design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">
      <sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
         <feature number="48">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz" />
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
            <per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
            <per fre="Volum_40mb" value="44.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
            <per fre="Volum_70mb" value="77.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
         </mwan>
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
            <xyz abc="trt" id="abc" />
            <per fre="acc" value="abc" />
            <per fre="xyz" value="abc" />
            <per fre="yy" value="abc" />
            <per fre="Volum_5mb" value="77.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
            <per fre="Volum_40mb" value="65.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
            <per fre="Volum_70mb" value="94.00" />
            #new attribute FYI
         </mwan>
      </sec>
      #file continue....
   </design>
</brand>
```

I am trying etree.ElementTree module

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for i in range(len(df)):
    for node in tree.findall("./design/sec"):
        name = node.attrib.get('name')
        if  name == df.loc[i, 'name']:
            print(name)
```

I am new to this Python-XML coding. I dont have any idea how to add new attributes in a XML file by using pandas data frame.
Please help.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: first learn how to use `xlm.etree` and how to [Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) because your main problem has nothing to do directly with `pandas`. How about `node.set("value", "89.00")`

Comment: you could first find all nodes and later use them with `df` - this way you would search every node only once. In current code you search the same node many times.

Comment: BTW: `node = tree.findall('./design/sec[@name="M_20_K40745170"]')` and later you can do `node.find('./per[@fre="Volum_5mb"]\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could learn `xml` and `xpath` because main problem has nothing do to with `pandas` but `xml`.

You can use more complex `xpath` to find node with name `M_20_K40745170` and subnode `mwam` in which you will have to search `pre` and update it (or even add new `pre`)

```
node = root.find('./design/sec[@name="M_20_K40745170"]//mwan')
```

You can use `df.iterrows()` for this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    node = root.find('./design/sec[@name="{}"]//mwan'.format(row['name']))
```

And later you can search `per` with `"Volum_5mb"`

```
item = node.find('./per[@fre="Volum_5mb"]')
```

and create new one and/or update value

```
if not item:  # if item is None:
    item = ET.SubElement(node, 'per')
    item.set('fre', "Volum_5mb")

item.set('value', str(row['Volum_5mb']))
```

And you can use list `['Volum_5mb', 'Volum_40mb', 'Volum_70mb']` for this

```
for fre in ['Volum_5mb', 'Volum_40mb', 'Volum_70mb']:

    item = node.find('./per[@fre="{}"]'.format(fre))
    #print(fre, item)

    if not item:
        item = ET.SubElement(node, 'per')
        item.set('fre', fre)

    item.set('value', str(row[fre]))
```

---

Minimal working code with example data directly in code but you should read them from file.

```
text = '''                name       Volum_5mb      Volum_40mb     Volum_70mb
1     M_20_K40745170         89.00           44.00         77.00
2     M_20_K40745171         77.00           65.00         94.00'''

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
   <design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">
      <sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
         <feature number="48">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz" />
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
         </mwan>
      </sec>
      <sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
         <feature number="5748">
            <tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec" />
         </feature>
         <mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
            <xyz abc="trt" id="abc" />
            <per fre="acc" value="abc" />
            <per fre="xyz" value="abc" />
            <per fre="yy" value="abc" />
         </mwan>
      </sec>
   </design>
</brand>'''

import pandas as pd
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
#print(df)

#tree = ET.('input.xml')
#root = tree.getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    node = root.find('./design/sec[@name="{}"]//mwan'.format(row['name']))
    
    for fre in ['Volum_5mb', 'Volum_40mb', 'Volum_70mb']:

        item = node.find('./per[@fre="{}"]'.format(fre))
        #print('item:', fre, '=', item)

        if not item:
            #print('new', item, fre)
            item = ET.SubElement(node, 'per')
            #item.tail = '\n         '  # to pretty print
            item.set('fre', fre)

        item.set('value', str(row[fre]))

    #print(ET.tostring(node).decode())
    
#---
    
print( ET.tostring(root) )
#tree.write('output.xml')
```

---

Doc: [Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

Comment: you are adding and `pre` as new attribute instead of `per` since you are searching/ checking with `pre with "Volum_5mb"` anyway you will get `None`btw thanks for the explanation